# How automatically add comments in the start and end of an HTML block using a shortcut

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, comments, shortcut, emmet

I am looking for a shortcut which can produce HTML comments automatically at the Top and End of the HTML block. Now I am taking too much time to type comments which I want to avoid by using a shortcut. Is there any tool can help to meet my requirement. If so it will be very helpfull. I tried VS Code Emmet, but it only adds comments at the bottom of the HTML Block. If i can get a solution inside VS Code itself with using Emmet or any other extension, it would be much helpful. Following is my requirement. Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- Profile: Start -->
<div class='profile'>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
</dvi>
<!-- Profile: End -->
```

Comment: Do you want this on html creation, like `div.profile` or by applying the comments after the block exists - perhaps by selecting it first and trigger something that adds the start and end comments?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that, what I do is just the "ctrl + /" for each line, you just have to comment each line manually but with a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for regions.

Regioning code is available in lots of languages and IDEs.
For VSCODE take a look at this link: [Region Folder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder)

Using regions also has extra advantages like folding code with portions you like.

Comment: Is the region relevant to HTML markup. Thinks that its more relevant to Programming Languages. This is just my assumption. But it was helpfull to know another knowledge from you. Thanks for sharing !

Comment: No, region is not relevant to HTML. As you mentioned it is available in lots of development environments and languages.